# Upgrade Data Factory to GA API

Tags: azure-data-factory

This morning, when I logged in to the Data Factory UI, I was presented with the following message:

[image]
I clicked "Cancel" as we weren't quite ready to upgrade at the time, but now that we have ensured that all our PowerShell scripts, etc. are unaffected, we want to perform the upgrade. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere in the ADF UI nor in the Azure portal, where we can initiate the upgrade, and the message box no longer shows up when logging into ADF. How do we proceed?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a banner on top of your authoring screen that has the upgrade button. If that's not showing please refresh your browser and the banner should show up again :)
Let me know if this solves it.